# Zeppelin PySpark - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Tags: python, docker, pyspark, docker-compose, apache-zeppelin

Could you please help me resolve this error in PySpark (Zeppelin)?

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:139)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:299)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:408)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am trying to run this PySpark code:

```
%pyspark

df = pd.read_csv('/datos/cite75_99.txt.bz2', compression='bz2', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')
df.show()
```

I am running this code on a Zeppelin notebook built on a Docker compose.

This is what the docker-compose.yml file contains:

```
version: '2'
services:

  zeppelin:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        - "4040:4040"
    volumes:
        - ./logs:/logs
        - ./notebook:/notebook
        - ./datos:/datos
    environment:
        - ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR=/logs
        - ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR=/notebook
```

The Docker file for the Zeppelin service is as follows:

```
FROM apache/zeppelin:0.8.2
MAINTAINER tf.pena@usc.es
USER root
ENV LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 \ 
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV ZEPPELIN_ADDR=0.0.0.0
RUN echo "Instalando locales" && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y locales 

RUN locale-gen $LANG &&\
    update-locale LANG=$LANG

RUN echo "Instalando paquetes adicionales" && \
    apt-get install -y netcat-openbsd 

ENV SPARK_VERSION=2.2.0 \
    HADOOP_VERSION=2.7 \
    SPARK_DIR=/usr/local 
ENV SPARK_HOME=${SPARK_DIR}/spark
RUN echo "Instalando Spark" && \ 
    mkdir -p ${SPARK_DIR} && \
    wget -O /tmp/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz && \
    tar -zxf /tmp/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz && \
    rm -rf /tmp/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz && \
    mv -f spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION} ${SPARK_DIR} && \
    ln -s ${SPARK_DIR}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION} ${SPARK_HOME}

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 4040
```

It is worth mentioning that system shell codes are running in the same Zeppelin notebook succesfully.

Looking forward to your input.

Thank you!

Comment: It will be nice to see at least docker-compose.yml

Comment: Sure. I added it to the question.... Looking forward to your feedback. Thank you!

Comment: OK. I, guess, it will be very nice to show your Dockerfile for zeppelin service

Comment: @ozlevka, sure. I added that at the end of the question... Any idea please about how to fix this error?

Comment: You should start spark into a docker container. Currently, you have the zeppelin running only. See this repo as example https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-spark